# How to setup a Share point Link for a google extension

Tags: sharepoint, https, intranet

So, I am trying to implement a SharePoint intranet site for an organization. However, there is one application in particular that they would like a link to on the homepage. Unfortunately this application can only be used via the IE tab google chrome extension (I know, dumb) but app devs have yet to add chromium compatibility.

Any way the link looks like this:
chrome-extension:
//hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd/nhc.htm#url=https://website.com/sub/sub.Hub.aspx

But share point requires a https:// on the beginning of a link.

If you throw that destination into chrome directly it navigates fine, but if you add say https://google.com/ on the front or https://*/ it doesn't work.

Is there a syntax that will allow me to put https:// on the front of this without getting a 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I ended up re-directing this through IIS internally

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).